# ios 8 device orientation landscape

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, orientation

my app's views are forced to portrait except one view (movie player) which is landscape.
In the landscape view, I have :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

the device is in landscape but the view still in portrait mode :[image]

(what you see in the simulator is what I can see in my real device)

Everything works fine for iOS prior to 8.0

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

for iOS 8